# Circualr progress bar for Audio

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

Now I am developing an app which includes music. On that I am using AVAudio player for playing music. My issue is that I need to show a circular progress bar with Play/Pause buttons. The sample image is attached with this.[image: Screen]

How can I achieve this.

Comment: Something like  [this](https://github.com/elbryan/FFCircularProgressView)

Comment: I hav gone through this but i didn't find any options to pause and play it again. Is it ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use components for example
[LLACircularProgressView](https://github.com/lipka/LLACircularProgressView)

or
[UAProgresssView](https://github.com/UrbanApps/UAProgressView)

and you can get  lengh of your audio with :

```
audioplauer.duration
```

Comment: On the UAProgresssView how can we set the time duration for the animation. I have tried with "animationDuration", but its not working

Answer (score 0):

There are some good suggestions above.

You could also use a `UIView`, set its layer content to the image, and add a `CALayer` in which you draw the progress arc and `CAShapeLayer`s or filled `CALayer`s to draw the Play/Resume shapes. `CALayer`s are light-weight and straight-forward to work with. You would capture the users touch in the usual way - with a gesture recognizer added to the UIView.

I personally find it is often easier to roll my own in a case like this than to deal with the integration of external projects, mainly because they tend to be much more general than I need, and the amount of work understanding how to integrate them, how to strip out what I don't need etc. ends up being greater than the work needed to make this component myself.

That being said, you should realize that if you roll your own, you have to debug and test thoroughly - whereas with third-party code you are (hopefully) benefitting from the testing of many other people.

For an introduction to CALayers, see the WWDC 2010 session "Core Animation in Practice - Part 1" (full disclosure: I was the presenter).